# ubuntu 20: <Error> CPU pipe A F10 underrun

Tags: nvidia, suspend, screen, cpu, intel-cpu

I get the error an error:
****  CPU pipe A FIFO underun
when I open my Laptop Lid after it was closed. Sometimes also after disconnecting a monitor. Then I cannot continue to use my laptop.

I appreciate help

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  No such release; do you mean Ubuntu Core 20? as that's usually used as a *headless* OS as it's not a desktop release (desktop systems are *year.month* in format & different products to those using the *year* format).

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS